# Line and column numbers in vim status line

Tags: vim, statusline

On some of my systems, I can see the line and column at the bottom of the display when using vim, along with an indication of the window's position.

[image: terminals on different systems showing the related bottom-of-page differences]

But I'm not able to find a way to make this appear on other systems. This does not seem to be OS level dependent, as the results are different on same-os-level systems.  Having said that, these are various levels of Ubuntu from 16.04 to 20.04.  The image above is from two systems that are each running 20.04.

I thought this might be some setting in the status line, but it appears that this indicator is separate from the status line.  I've copied my /etc/vim/vimrc and my ~/.vimrc files between the systems, with no change at all. Using vim command :set , I cannot see any differences that would cause this.

Can you help me understand what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is likely a `vi` vs `vim` issue...something like one server is using `/bin/vi` while the other is using `/usr/bin/vim`. For me, `/bin/vi` has no line and column numbers in the status line but `/usr/bin/vim` does.

Comment: YAY!!!!! @matt I don't remember ever choosing to install vim on any of my systems ... when I began using ubuntu (back when the earth was still cooling) I didn't much care for (buggy, back then) vim, and I actually took steps to prevent its installation.  That was then.  Now I just don't pay it any attention since both seem to work for me.  I tried it - sudo apt install vim - and it worked a treat.  Ah well, some things we take for granted are actually a godsend.  I appreciate the response, and have accepted your answer.

Comment: This is a `vim` vs `vim` issue, not `vi` vs `vim`.